# pip install `opencv-contrib-python` stuck at "building wheels for opencv-contrib-python" on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to install `opencv-contrib-python` on my Raspberry Pi using [this](https://youtu.be/QzVYnG-WaM4) youtube tutorial. I have also tried other tutorials on youtube but every single time it gets stuck for hours at **"Building wheels for opencv-contrib-python (pyproject.toml)"**. I know that the installation takes a lot of time but hell i have given it more than 24 hours but it gets stuck at that particular part and then my raspberry pi automatically gets either frozen or it reboots automatically resulting in installation failure.

I am using **Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2**

Some points to know that

1. There are plenty of space available (almost 7GB)
2. I have given it the time it requires as i mentioned above
3. I also tried to follow the official docs and tried to build it from [source](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html) but it stuck at **98%**

attaching below image for reference

[opencv-contrib-python-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj8Fh.jpg)

Comment: try setting MAKEFLAGS environment variable to -j1, eg `export MAKEFLAGS=-j1` before pip. It might help but will definitely take even longer